# How many copies of the variable C are created by this snippet of code?

Tags: c++, operating-system

For some homework, I need to figure out how many copies of the variable "c" are created by this program, as well as their values. An explanation would be nice as well, as I am trying to recover from having a not so great computer science professor in my first year.

Here is the code snippet:

```
  int child = fork();
  int c = 5;
  if (child == 0) 
  {
     c += 5;
  } 
  else
  {
     child = fork();
     c += 10;
     if (child) 
     {
         c += 10;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Could you maybe format the code so we can read it?

Comment: (And does anyone really use `fork()` anymore??)

Comment: So... what are your thoughts at the moment? How many are you thinking are created, and why?

Comment: I'm not really sure what to look for, I did the reading in my textbook. I see alot of concepts, but I did not see much in the way of actual code. I do know that since a child process is being created, there are two processes being run, and that the child process will always return 0. After that, I am not really sure where to go.

Comment: I also know that the parent and child both have copies of the necessary resources, so the amount of copies would have to factor that in.

Comment: Test it? Take a reference to the variable and change it through that reference. Did the value change? Is it the same? At least.. I think that'd work.

Comment: @HotLicks: yes, people use `fork()` — what do you use?

Comment: Why not try it?  print out 'Here's one!' when a 'c' var is declared.  Run the code, see the output:)

Answer (score 1):

There are three processes in total, so there end up being 3 copies of `c`.

1. In the first child, the value of `c` is `10` (5 from `int c = 5;` and 5 from `c += 5;`).
2. In the second child, the value of `c` is `15` (5 from `int c = 5;` and 10 from the first `c += 10;`).
3. In the parent, the value of `c` is `25` (5 from `int c = 5;` and 10 from the first `c += 10;` and 10 from the second `c += 10;`).